# Deleting all records of a table that are not referenced from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

2 tables:
items(id, ...)
users(id, item_id, ...)

How do you delete all records in *items* that are not referenced from *users*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beware that NOT IN may be really slow. Sometimes - surpringly enough - its faster to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM items EXCEPT SELECT item_id FROM users)
```

Comment: This is good in some other SQL languages, but MySQL does not support EXCEPT.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM users)
```

(uses a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html) to select all the `item_ids` from `users` and then deletes the records from `items` where `id` is not in the results of that subquery)

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from items
where id not in (select item_id from users)
```