# SQL: Performance comparison for exclusion (Join vs Not in)

Tags: sql, performance, join

I am curious on the most efficient way to query exclusion on sql. E.g. There are 2 tables (tableA and tableB) which can be joined on 1 column (col1). I want to display the data of tableA for all the rows which col1 does not exist in tableB.

(So, in other words, tableB contains a subset of col1 of tableA. And I want to display tableA without the data that exists in tableB)

Let's say tableB has 100 rows while tableA is gigantic (more than 1M rows). I know 'Not in (not exists)' can be used but perhaps there are more efficient ways (less comp. time) to do it.? I don't maybe with outer joins?

Code snippets and comments are much appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle? The capabilities of the query optimizers in these differ.

Comment: Oracle. I will be surprised if there are significant performance differences over various DBMS.

Comment: Yes, you will be surprised. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the RDBMS. For Microsoft SQL Server [NOT EXISTS is preferred](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) to the OUTER JOIN as it can use the more efficient Anti-Semi join.

For Oracle [Minus is apparently preferred](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_sql_tune.htm) to NOT EXISTS (where suitable)

You would need to look at the execution plans and decide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DBMS that I am interested in is Oracle. Are you sure that Minus is more efficient than a query with join or inflagranti's answer?

Comment: @masa44 Nope not at all. Though inflagranti's answer uses EXCEPT which *is* Minus in Oracle. The recommendation was to look at the execution plans.

Comment: +1 for recommending to investigate execution plans (on real data with updated statistics). Also the question is which indexes are present.

Comment: Thanks Martin Smith, good recommendation. If I were able, I would have also voted this up :)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use

```
Select a.Col1
From TableA a
Left Join TableB b on a.Col1 = b.Col1
Where b.Col1 Is Null
```

I believe this will be quicker as you are utilising the FK constraint (providing you have 
them of course)

Sample data:

```
create table #a
(
Col1 int
)
Create table #b
(
col1 int
)

insert into #a
Values (1)
insert into #a
Values (2)
insert into #a
Values (3)
insert into #a
Values (4)

insert into #b
Values (1)
insert into #b
Values (2)


Select a.Col1
From #a a 
Left Join #b b on a.col1 = b.Col1
Where b.Col1 is null
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this solution does not work for me. One reason is Col1 cannot be null (tableB has only Col1). So your solution gives me no results.

Comment: @Masa44 - Are you sure? It works for me fine.  I've added some test data as an example.

Comment: Barry, thanks for the example. Your example works just fine but I failed to do so in my case, I guess I am making a small error.

Answer (score 1):

The questions has been asked several times. The often fastest way is to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT id FROM table2)
```

As the whole joining can be done on indexes, where using NOT IN it generally cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't find previously asked questions.

Comment: This for instance I think is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074862/deleting-all-records-of-a-table-that-are-not-referenced-from-another-table/3074873#3074873

Comment: Yes, that's similar. But it's difficult to find that question as it lacks detailed description and tags. You know it because you answered that one 2 days ago :)

Comment: Hehe. Yeah, I tried finding it through manual search myself first too and I couldnt. So I may have had an advantage there ;)

Comment: Have you any references to back up your statement? I am interested to see some statistics.

Comment: My personal experience was with DB2 where I could greatly improve some query. Seems to be the same for Oracle according to Martin Smith's answer. I guess with NOT IN the optimizer has to be more clever to get the same performance (IMO the fastest way for NOT IN would be to rewrite it to doing a set subtraction on the ID's in the indexes on table1 and table2 and then get the values from table1 using the ID's, which is exactly what is spilled out in the query I suggested).

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer to this question. Every RDBMS has query optimizer that will determine best execution plan based on available indices, table statistics (number of rows, index selectivity), join condition, query condition, ...

When you have relatively simple query like in your question, there is often several ways you can get results in SQL. Every self respecting RDBMS will recognize your intention and will create same execution plan, no matter which syntax you use (subqueries with IN or EXISTS operator, query with JOIN, ...)

So, best solution here is to write simplest query that works and then check execution plan.
If that solution is not acceptable then you should try to find better query.

Comment: No, databases will not generate the same plan for differnt types of queries that have teh same result set. If you look vendor by vendor you will find out which are the most efficient ways to do specific types of queries.

Comment: @HLGEM You obviously never looked at execution plans in Oracle in situation described in question.

Comment: NO I l;ook at the execution plans in SQL server where there is huge differnce between such differnt approaches to the same query. ANd knowing that I know which type to try first. Write the simplest query is just bad advice. ANd "Every self respecting RDBMS will recognize your intention and will create same execution plan, no matter which syntax you use" is just plain false.