# MySQL lookup joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have 3 tables, location, lookup and exclude with the following info...

location table

```
+----+--------------+
| id | location     |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | Location a   |
| 2  | Location b   |
| 3  | Location c   |
| 5  | Location d   |
| 6  | Location e   |
| 7  | Location f   |
| 8  | Location g   |
| 9  | Location h   |
+----+--------------+
```

lookup table

```
+----+-------------+------+
| id | location_id | code |
+----+-------------+------+
| 1  | 2           | PR6  |
| 2  | 2           | PR7  |
| 3  | 2           | PR9  |
| 4  | 5           | WA2  |
| 6  | 8           | WA3  |
+----+-------------+------+
```

exclude table

```
+----+-------------+------+
| id | location_id | code |
+----+-------------+------+
| 1  | 2           | PR5  |
| 2  | 2           | PR8  |
+----+-------------+------+
```

These tables exist for a basic postcode lookup. I need to create some SQL so a search can be done using the postcode but I need to take into account any excluded postcodes so for example... If I was to search for "PR7" I would get "Location B" as the result but if I was to search for PR5 or PR8, I would not get "Location B" as these are in the exclude table. Here is what I have so far....

```
SELECT
lookup.*, exclude.`code` as exclude, location.location
FROM lookup
LEFT JOIN
exclude
ON lookup.location_id = exclude.location_id
LEFT JOIN
location
ON location.location = lookup.location_id
WHERE lookup.`code` LIKE 'PR%' AND (exclude.`code` NOT LIKE 'PR8%' OR ISNULL(exclude.`code`))
GROUP BY location.location
ORDER BY location.id
```

In my SQL above, the user typed "PR8" which is being sent to the where clause using PHP variables, I look for the 1st 2 letters of the postcode in the lookup table and then I am also trying to look for what the user entered in the exclude table to omit this from the results. Unfortunately I cant tell where I am going wrong, I am getting the following results where as based on the above tables I should be getting no results due to the exclusion...

```
+----+-------------+------+---------+
| id | location    | code | exclude |
+----+-------------+------+---------+
| 1  | Location b  | PR8  | PR5     |
+----+-------------+------+---------+
```

I hope I have explained this well enough but please tell me if I need to add more detail.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this, thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to exclude the rows where code is in Exclude table, or do you want location as Null, if the code exist in Exclude table?

Comment: Hi Sonam, thanks for your response. I need to exclude the rows and Geoffrey's suggestion of using NOT IN in my AND did the trick :) happy days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use "NOT IN".

So your "AND" would be more like

```
AND lookup.`code` NOT IN (SELECT 'code' FROM exclude)
```

EDIT
I'm pretty sure this would work, not sure about best performance, I'll leave that to smarter people than I.

```
SELECT
lookup.*, location.location
FROM lookup
LEFT JOIN
location
ON location.id = lookup.location_id
WHERE lookup.`code` LIKE 'PR%' 
AND lookup.`code` NOT IN (SELECT `code` FROM exclude) 
GROUP BY location.location
ORDER BY location.id
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3083665/2237306 I guess NOT IN may not be the way to go.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thanks for your help on this :) I have tested the NOT IN as you suggested and it seems to be working fine now, even though the post you linked to indicates NOT IN is not the way to go. Thank you sooo much, I have been on with this query for the past 2 hours, you sir are a life saver.